# How to Create a filter/drop down menu in VBA with user input

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, input, import

currently my code prompts the user to enter a comma separated list of titles. However, is there a way i can change the code so instead the user can search for the title desired from a drop down menu, click a checkbox by the title, and able to keep searching for required titles until done. And store these strings in an array.

```
    Dim arWords() As String
    myt = InputBox("Enter User Input")
    arWords() = Split(myt, ",")
        For X = 0 To UBound(arWords)
        myf = myf & arWords(X) & vbNewLine
    Next X
```

I have an array (arrH) later in the code that has all the titles stored so i think id have to use this as the source, if i need one?. Or so i believe. Im still learning.

```
arrH = Split(arrTxt(HeaderRow), vbTab)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a UserForm.

"the user can search for the title desired from a drop down menu, click a checkbox by the title, and able to keep searching for required titles until done".

UserForm with a ComboBox & CheckBox. On CheckBox_Change event, have the script store the value of ComboBox to a public module-level array and iterate the array index.

Have a "Done" button that hides the userform.

Here's what the Userform code module looks like:

```vb
Public SelectedTitles As Variant, ArrCount As Long, EnableEvents As Boolean

Private Sub CheckBox1_Change()
    'User has indicated they want to add the currently selected item to the list
    If Not EnableEvents Then Exit Sub
    If ArrCount = 0 Then 'First item, create the array
        SelectedTitles = Array("")
    Else
        ReDim Preserve SelectedTitles(UBound(SelectedTitles) + 1) 'Next items, add one more space in the array
    End If
    
    'Add the selected title to the array
    SelectedTitles(ArrCount) = ComboBox1.Value
    
    'Increment the counter
    ArrCount = ArrCount + 1
    
    'Reset the checkbox and the combobox
    EnableEvents = False
    CheckBox1.Value = False
    ComboBox1.Value = ""
    EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    'Done Button
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Here is a sub to aid in adding items to a ComboBox list:

```vb
Sub ComboBox_AddFromArray(ByRef ComboBox As Object, ListArray As Variant)
    ComboBox.Clear
    If IsArray(ListArray) Then
        Dim i As Long
        For i = LBound(ListArray) To UBound(ListArray)
            ComboBox.AddItem ListArray(i), ComboBox.ListCount
        Next i
    Else
        ComboBox.AddItem ListArray, 0
    End If
End Sub
```

This function would go after `Load UserForm1` and before `UserForm1.Show`. And you would input the arguments like `ComboBox_AddFromArray UserForm1.ComboBox1, arrH`.

The way you'd put this all together is by having a controlling function that does all of the Userform processes and then returns what you need, which is that user selected array of titles.

This is what that would look like

```vb
Function UserInputForm(ByRef ArrayOfAllTitles As Variant) As Variant
    Load UserForm1
    ComboBox_AddFromArray UserForm1.ComboBox1, ArrayOfAllTitles
    UserForm1.Show
    UserInputForm = UserForm1.SelectedTitles
    Unload UserForm1
End Function
```

And Finally, an example of how to include that function into your main sub:

```vb
Dim SelectedTitles As Variant
SelectedTitles = UserInputForm(arrH)
'SelectedTitles is now an array of Variant/String values

Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(SelectedTitles) To UBound(SelectedTitles)
    Debug.Print SelectedTitles(i)
    'Access individual members of the array using SelectedTitles(i)
Next i
```

Comment: Hey @Toddleson, thanks for responding. Just wanted to ask, does it make a difference if the source those Titles the user would be searching from are in a .txt file.

Comment: @kyle Once you have the list of titles, from whatever source, you just need to put them into the ComboBox using the `ComboBox.Add` method. If you don't know how to extract them from a text file, that is a separate question.

Comment: Oh nope, I already got them in an array! Right now im just learning on how to create the userform and such. Thanks!

Comment: @kyle I added an example of how to add items to a combobox from an array

Comment: Thanks! Do i go ahead and put this in the private sub for the combobox? Or rather the private sub for the userform initialization?

Comment: Also, not sure if im allowed to ask. How can i create an array from the selected titles from the userform?

Comment: @kyle Ok, I have added a fully fleshed out example of what the userform code would look like and how to put it all together. I hope you enjoy your time coding in VBA, it wont always be as easy as today :p

Comment: Sir, you are a magician. Thanks you. And yeah I wont forget these exercises, for sure will continue to practice. Thanks!